# simple email validation using PCRE to validate the end of a string

Tags: php

Im just trying to validate an email ending with a particular string.  Im using PCRE for this...but cant seem to get it to work.  The email needs to end in either boisestate.edu or u.boisestate.edu.  I've been stabbing at this one for awhile...some help would be really appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

```
if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]+[a-z0-9A-Z_-]+@[\.u]?\.boisestate\.edu$/", "melissa@boisestate.edu", $matches)){
echo "Match was found <br />";
print_r($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to do the whole email match and domain check in one, you could just `filter_var` and a much simpler regex for domain validation.

Example:

```
function check_email($address) {
    if (filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
            && preg_match('/@(u\.)?boisestate\.edu$/', $address)) {
        print "We have a match!\n";
    } else {
        print "Match failed!\n";
    }
}
```

When called like this:

```
check_email('garbage');
check_email('foo@example.com');
check_email('me@u.boisestate.edu');
check_email('you@boisestate.edu');
```

You'll get the output:

```
Match failed!
Match failed!
We have a match!
We have a match!
```

---

As far as the regex is concerned, the reason why yours is failing, is because you're searching for one of the chars in the square-brackets, only once.

So, you would match things like `foo@.boisestate.edu` and `foo@uboisestate.edu`.  If you use parenthesis instead of square brackets, the `?` will optionally match the entire contents inside the parens.

```
@(u\.)?boisestate\.edu$
```

Comment: doesn't the + indicate one or more?

Comment: Yes, but that's one or more of any of the items.  So in the case of square brackets, that could be `uuuuu` or `...` or even (correctly) `u.`, but it's far too permissive for you requirements of `boisestate.edu` or `u.boisestate.edu`.  You were right to try to use `?`, since you only want this `u.` to possibly match once, or not at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]+[a-z0-9A-Z_-]+@[u\.]*boisestate\.edu$/",     "melissa@boisestate.ed", $matches)){
echo "Match was found <br />";
print_r($matches);
}
```

Ok, and this is the revised version:

```
if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9A-Z_-]+@(?:u\.)*boisestate\.edu$/", "melissa@u.boisestate.edu", $matches)){
echo "Match was found <br />";
print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: You can also remove the redundant `[a-zA-Z]+` from the beginning. And I'm trying to improve it, so that it doesn't match melissa@uu.boisestate.edu...

Comment: This regex will also match things like `uuu.boisestate.edu`, and even `uboisestate.edu`

Comment: the redundant [a-zA-Z] was to ensure that the string started with a letter as apposed to a number

Comment: @AdamWagner Well, the revised one shouldn't :)